# regex: Find first and last name starting with same letter

Tags: regular-expression

I have a task that I need to find in the contents of a file the lines containing first and last name that both start with the same letter. Everything I have tried only searches for the first letter in the first name or just doesn't output anything. Can I get some guidance on where to go on this?

Data that needed to be parsed:

```
Frank Smith
Jim Jones
William Tuft
Jill Johnston
Fred White
Sue Cream
Barbara Bennett
Jeff Gordo
```

I figured it out using this egrep command:

```
egrep '(J[a-z]+ J)' addresses.txt
```

*for privacy reasons, I removed the addresses

Comment: Can you give an example? Post it in th quetion, not in tha comments.

Comment: We cannot help you parse data you don't show. Please [edit] your question and include i) a few lines of your input file and ii) the output you would want from that file. Human names are notoriously difficult to parse though. Consider _Jorge Francisco Isidoro Luis Borges Acevedo_ or _Xi Jinping_ or _John Henry Batterdown-Hatchingson_. What's the last name there?

Answer (score 2):

```
$ grep -E '^[[:space:]]*([[:alpha:]])[[:alpha:]]*[[:space:]]+\1' yourfile.txt
```

The `grep` command will search *yourfile.txt* for:

1. Any number of space characters (`*` means 0 or more) in the beginning of line, followed by
2. Exactly one alphabetic character, followed by
3. Any number of alphabetic characters (`*` means 0 or more), followed by
4. At least one space character (`+` means 1 or more), followed by
5. The character matched in step 2. Here `\1` is a *back-reference* to the actual string matched by the *first* parenthesized exression.

Note: The following command (using ***basic*** instead of ***extended*** regular expression) has the same effect as the one given above:

```
$ grep '^[[:space:]]*\([[:alpha:]]\)[[:alpha:]]*[[:space:]]\+\1' yourfile.txt
```

Comment: Backreferences are not defined in the extended regular expression standard (although I think that most implementations support it anyhow). So BRE is preferred.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a list of names:

```
$ cat file
George Washington
Ronald Reagan
Barack Obama
Donald Trump

$ awk 'substr($1,1,1) == substr($NF,1,1)' file
Ronald Reagan
```

As I use `$NF` (= the last field) for last name, it will work well if you have middle names, but it will fail miserably if you have a suffix like `Jr.` or a prefix like `Mr.` or `Dr.`.

Answer (score -2):

```
egrep '(J[a-z]+ J)' file.txt
```

Output:

Jim Jones

Jill Johnston

Comment: except that this obviously hard-codes the letter "J", missing "Barbara Bennett"; you'd have to repeat this for every other letter to have a general answer.